# ggpubr not creating multiple bars in ggdotchart

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Utilizing the example package code in `ggpubr`, the `ggdotchart` function does not create separate segments as is shown in the example, instead there is only a single segment, though the dots seem to be placed in the correct orientation.  Does anyone have any tips on what the problem may be?  I've thought it may be due to factors, tibbles vs. df, but I haven't been able to determine the problem.

Code:

```
df <- diamonds %>%
  filter(color %in% c("J", "D")) %>%
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  summarise(counts = n()) 

ggdotchart(df, x = "cut", y ="counts",
           color = "color", palette = "jco", size = 3, 
           add = "segment", 
           add.params = list(color = "lightgray", size = 1.5),
           position = position_dodge(0.3),
           ggtheme = theme_pubclean()
           )
```

With the expected output of:
[image]

But instead I am getting:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to get your desired plot without `ggpubr::ggdotchart`. The issue seems to be that `geom_segment` does not allow dodging, as discussed here: [R - ggplot dodging geom_lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227482/r-ggplot-dodging-geom-lines) and here: [how to jitter/dodge geom_segments so they remain parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904364/how-to-jitter-dodge-geom-segments-so-they-remain-parallel).

```
# your data
df <- diamonds %>%
  filter(color %in% c("J", "D")) %>%
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())
```

The first step is to expand your data. We will need this when we call `geom_line` which allows for dodging. I took this idea from [@Stibu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36233588/8583393). We create a copy of `df` and change the `counts` column to be `0` in `df2`. Finally we use `bind_rows` to create a single data frame from `df` and `df2`.

```
df2 <- df
df2$counts <- 0

df_out <- purrr::bind_rows(df, df2)
df_out
```

Then I use `ggplot` to create / replicate your desired output.

```
ggplot(df_out, aes(x = cut, y = counts)) +
  geom_line(
    aes(col = color), # needed for dodging, we'll later change colors to "lightgrey"
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.3),
    show.legend = FALSE,
    size = 1.5
  ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(fill = color),
    data = subset(df_out, counts > 0),
    col = "transparent",
    shape = 21,
    size = 3,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("lightgray", "lightgray")) + #change line colors
  ggpubr::fill_palette(palette = "jco") +
  ggpubr::theme_pubclean()
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that `geom_segments` didn't allow for dodging, now it all makes sense! Thanks @markus

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra "group" argument you need!

```
    df <- diamonds %>%
  dplyr::filter(color %in% c("J", "D")) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(cut, color) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(counts = n())

ggdotchart(df, x = "cut", y ="counts",
           color = "color", group="color", # here it is
           palette = "jco", size = 3, 
           add = "segment", 
           add.params = list(color = "lightgray", size = 1.5),
           position = position_dodge(0.3),
           ggtheme = theme_pubclean()
)
```

[image: Fixed plot:]